# Spark standalone cluster - having trouble reading data from local files

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Hello Stack Overflow community,

I have set up a Spark cluster in standalone mode with three machines: one master and two worker nodes.
My goal is to run a simple PySpark application that reads a text file and prints its contents.

Here's the code snippet for my PySpark application:

```py
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf

master_url = "spark://<SPARK_MASTER_IP>:7077"

conf = SparkConf().setAppName("print_lines").setMaster(master_url)
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)

input_file = "/data/example.txt"

distFile = sc.textFile(f"file://{input_file}")

for line in distFile.collect():
    print(line)

sc.stop()
```

I am submitting this application from the same machine where the master node resides, using the following command:

```bash
./bin/spark-submit --master "spark://<SPARK_MASTER_IP>:7077" -c "spark.driver.bindAddress=0.0.0.0" -c "spark.driver.host=<THIS_HOST_IP>" -c "spark.driver.port=50070" -c "spark.driver.blockManager.port=50080" --driver-memory "500m" --executor-cores 1 myApp.py
```

Some relevant information about my setup:

- Spark version: 3.4.1
- The master and worker nodes each have 1 vCPU and 2GB of RAM.
- Worker node configuration (set through `spark-env.sh`):

  - `SPARK_DAEMON_MEMORY="300m"`
  - `SPARK_WORKER_CORES=1`
  - `SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY="1000m"`
- The application is run with 500MB of memory for the driver (specified with `--driver-memory`) and 1 CPU core per executor (specified with `--executor-cores`).

The file `/data/example.txt` exists on the local filesystem of all three machines, but it contains different content on each copy. Specifically:

- On worker node 1:

  ```
  foo
  bar
  ```
- On worker node 2:

  ```
  baz
  foo
  bar
  ```
- On the driver program's host, the file is empty.

As per Spark documentation, I expected the application to print all the lines from all copies of the file.
However, I only get the content from one of the copies of the file.

Upon inspecting the Spark master web UI, I noticed that an executor is started on each worker node, but the `collect` job is only executed on one of the executors. Tasks are only being run on that specific executor, and not on the other.

Additionally, from the Event Timeline in the application web UI, it seems that one of the executors is registered only after the collect job has terminated.

The driver program's logs provide the following information:

> INFO SparkContext: Starting job: collect at /home/myuser/myApp.py:20
> INFO DAGScheduler: Got job 0 (collect at /home/myuser/myApp.py:20) with 2 output partitions
> INFO DAGScheduler: Final stage: ResultStage 0 (collect at /home/myuser/myApp.py:20)
> INFO DAGScheduler: Parents of final stage: List()
> INFO DAGScheduler: Missing parents: List()
> INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting ResultStage 0 (file:///data/example.txt MapPartitionsRDD[1] at textFile at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:0), which has no missing parents
> INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_1 stored as values in memory (estimated size 4.9 KiB, free 109.6 MiB)
> INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_1_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 2.8 KiB, free 109.6 MiB)
> INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_1_piece0 in memory on x.x.x.106:50080 (size: 2.8 KiB, free: 110.0 MiB)
> INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 1 from broadcast at DAGScheduler.scala:1535
> INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting 2 missing tasks from ResultStage 0 (file:///data/example.txt MapPartitionsRDD[1] at textFile at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:0) (first 15 tasks are for partitions Vector(0, 1))
> INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Adding task set 0.0 with 2 tasks resource profile 0
> INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend$StandaloneDriverEndpoint: Registered executor NettyRpcEndpointRef(spark-client://Executor) (x.x.x.107:55900) with ID 0,  ResourceProfileId 0
> INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager x.x.x.107:39662 with 110.0 MiB RAM, BlockManagerId(0, x.x.x.107, 39662, None)
> INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0) (x.x.x.107, executor 0, partition 0, PROCESS_LOCAL, 7418 bytes)
> INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_1_piece0 in memory on x.x.x.107:39662 (size: 2.8 KiB, free: 110.0 MiB)
> INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_0_piece0 in memory on x.x.x.107:39662 (size: 32.5 KiB, free: 110.0 MiB)
> INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1) (x.x.x.107, executor 0, partition 1, PROCESS_LOCAL, 7418 bytes)
> INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0) in 1368 ms on x.x.x.107 (executor 0) (1/2)
> INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1) in 56 ms on x.x.x.107 (executor 0) (2/2)
> INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 0.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool
> INFO DAGScheduler: ResultStage 0 (collect at /home/myuser/myApp.py:20) finished in 2.962 s
> INFO DAGScheduler: Job 0 is finished. Cancelling potential speculative or zombie tasks for this job
> INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Killing all running tasks in stage 0: Stage finished
> INFO DAGScheduler: Job 0 finished: collect at /home/myuser/myApp.py:20, took 3.075881 s
> foo
> bar
> INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend$StandaloneDriverEndpoint: Registered executor NettyRpcEndpointRef(spark-client://Executor) (x.x.x.108:36696) with ID 1,  ResourceProfileId 0
> INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager x.x.x.108:45255 with 110.0 MiB RAM, BlockManagerId(1, x.x.x.108, 45255, None)

It appears that no tasks are run on one of the executors (for example, the executor on machine `x.x.x.108`). Furthermore, the BlockManager server on this executor is registered only after the job is finished. Is this behavior normal?

I want to emphasize that there are no errors in the logs of the driver or in the stderr logs of the executors.

I suspect that I may be missing a fundamental understanding of how Spark works.
For instance, do I need to have a copy of the file on the driver program's host's local filesystem?
If I don't, Spark gives me an error similar to this:

> java.io.IOException: Input path does not exist: file:/data/example.txt

I've already attempted to increase worker node resources by adjusting the `SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY` configuration, but it did not change the outcome.
Unfortunately, I am limited to working with small machines with only 1 vCPU and a maximum of 2 GB of RAM for testing.

Any insights or guidance on what might be causing this behavior and how to resolve it would be greatly appreciated.